# Spring MVC equivalent of getText() from Struts for I18N

Tags: java, spring-mvc, struts2, internationalization

In Struts2 `ActionSupport` class has `getText(String key, ...)` method  that returns a localized message from i18n resource bundle. Is there any Spring MVC equivalent of this?

I know that there is `<spring:message>` tag, but it is not what I need. I need to retrieve localized message inside controller class, not on JSP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SpringMessage` source for this:

```
public class Example {

    private MessageSource messages;

    public void setMessages(MessageSource messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public void execute() {
        String message = this.messages.getMessage("argument.required",
            new Object [] {"userDao"}, "Required", null);
        System.out.println(message);
    }

}
```

See here for more info:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch03s13.html